# date as parameter in birt request

Tags: mysql, date, birt

i need to execute this request in birt report :

```
select * from user where date between ? and ?
```

I created tow string parameters, but the result is null.
When i do this request :

```
select * from user where date between '2018-03-13' and '2018-03-25'
```

it works

Comment: Please edit it from tow to two in 3rd line and tell me y do you want to execute your query where date between ? and ? ???

Comment: You should verify that your parameters are using the correct format.

Comment: hi, thanks for your messages,
I try it in php PDO, it works, but in birt doesn't work